# Store Pandas Dataframe to S3 with Secret Key

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-s3, parquet

How do we store a dataframe to S3 using our secret key in parquet format? What parameters can I add to the below code?

```
filename=file_name+'.parquet'
df.to_parquet('s3://path/'+filename)
```

Parameters/Logic for using Secret Key while storing parquet file to S3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use your access credentiels as headers in the `storage_options` a option for the `to_praquet`

like this :

```
s3_storage_options = {
    'key': 'acces_key',
    'secret': 'secret_key'
}
df.to_parquet('s3://bucket_name/file_name.parquet', storage_options=s3_storage_options)
```